# Why Page not found (404) while accessing child record in Onetomany relation in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am working on a small Django project and created OneToMany Relation between two models(say Products and Sub_Products). And my project contains two urls first to get all the data in products table and other link is to get related products associated with particular product.

I am passing product-id from template to view as follows:-

```
<a href='sub/{{ x.id }}'><img src="{{x.pic.url}}" alt="" class="card-img-top" height="200px"></a>
```

**url.py :-**

```
urlpatterns = [
                  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
                  path('home/', home_page_view, name='homepage'),
                  path('sub/<int:id>/', product_sub, name='relatedproducts'),
              ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**view Functions:-**

```
def product_sub(request, id):
    var = Products.objects.get(id=id)
    querysets = Sub_Products.objects.filter(products=var)
    context = {
        "object_list": querysets
    }
    print(context)
    return render(request, "subproducts.html", context)
```

Now when ever i am clicking on the image-link to get related project i am getting `Page not found (404)`.

**Exact Error:-**

```
“C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\ecommerceproject\media\home\sub\7” does not exist
```

But if i am using Shell to access the Sub_Products, i am getting desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use url names instead:

```
<a href="{% url 'relatedproducts' id=x.id %}"><img src="{{x.pic.url}}" alt="" class="card-img-top" height="200px"></a>
```